# get a form field value from fancybox iframe and return it to beforeClose function

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I am using jquery fancybox 2 to load an iframe form.
The form submits and writes the data to the database then closes the fancybox.
So that part of its all good.
However i want to retrieve a hidden field value from the iframe form.
This value will then hide the corresponding id on the parent page.
I try to get the hidden field value using the beforeClose option.
However i cannot get the hidden field value.

The hidden field has an pageload.
fancybox code:

```
$(".various").fancybox({
      maxWidth : 800,
      maxHeight   : 700,
      fitToView   : false,
      width    : '70%',
      height      : '90%',
      autoSize : false,
      closeClick  : false,
      openEffect  : 'fade',
      beforeClose : function(){
        var pageload = $('#pageload').val();            
        console.log('var = ' + pageload);
      },
      afterClose : function(){
        if(pageload != 0){
            $('#'+pageload).slideUp('slow');
        } else {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
      }
    });
```

and the fancybox is triggered by :

```
<a href="editcategory.php&pageload=<?php echo $sub_id; ?>" class='various' data-fancybox-type='iframe'>LINK</a>
```

When the iframe popsup there is :

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['pageload']; ?>" id="pageload" name="pageload" />
```

And all i need to do is return the pageload value back to the afterClose function.
I have tried using the afterLoad function to get value, the beforeClose function but none of them seem t give me an answer apart from null.
This will then 'slideup' that id and then clear it in the index page.

If the value = 0 it will do a page reload.

I have searched all day for an answer but they all seem very complex for probably a simple 2 line function.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to declare the variable `pageload` on the top of your script. Right now it is just valid inside the `beforeClose` callback function so

```
<script>
 var pageload;
 .
 .
```

then your fancybox callbacks

```
// we won't use beforeClose but beforeShow
beforeShow: function(){
 // get the value of pageload INSIDE the iframe
 pageload = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#pageload').val();
},
afterClose : function(){
 if(pageload != 0){
  $('#'+pageload).slideUp('slow');
 } else {
  window.location.reload(true);
 }
}
```

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.0.6+

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer.. I added the var pageload; right under my <script>. It failed to show any result , so i firebugged / alerted the pageload variable and it gave me the answer undefined.<br/>I am using fancybox v2.0.6

Comment: Sussed it.. Thanks for the help i need to use the afterShow function instead of the beforeShow and it worked perfect.

Comment: Maybe not... it worked first time and now fails with undefined again... i will keep trying...

Comment: make sure that the ID in `id="pageload"` is unique in your document

Comment: also make sure that your `.fancybox()` function is called after the document is ready ....see `$(document).ready()`